# How to connect to OpenVPN from Windows native interface

Tags: windows, vpn, openvpn, windows-10

This is quite a simple question. I'm trying to set up a VPN on a VPS and all of the sources I've read say "Use OpenVPN".

It also seems that with OpenVPN, you have to install this GUI on Windows in order to use it, but I'm just wondering - why couldn't I connect to my VPN with the inbuilt Windows VPN functionality?

I've used it to connect to other VPNs in the past (like my university's), and I would prefer to connect using this rather than have to install yet another program on to my already slow computer.

[image: Windows Network and Internet menu]

Answer (score 3):

The native VPN functionality in Windows is not compatible with OpenVPN. You'll either need to install an OpenVPn client or switch to a different VPN technology.